# jquery highlight() breaking in dynamic table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-plugins

I've got a little issue with a highlight function I'm working on.  I basically load records out of a database that match the current form data in certain ways.  Then, when someone is filling in the form, if they are describing an issue that already exists in my system, it will highlight words that their description has in common with the existing record(s).  My issue is that the table breaks.  It will work to a certain extent, but sometimes it breaks the PHP loop portion out of the rest of the table, and it then has no formatting, and the highlighting function will not work.  To be more specific, once broken, the td tags in the body of the table do not follow the formatting of the header row.
Conditions that cause the undesirable effect:

1. tabbing through the text area
2. If too many classes have to be removed or applied at once (via deleting all, adding many words or deleting or searching for a single character with many occurrences)

html on the main page && script to trigger the highlighting

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
<script>
 var delay = (function(){
 var timer = 0;
 return function(callback, ms){
 clearTimeout (timer);
 timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
 };
 })();
 $(function(){
    $("#description").keydown(function(){
    delay((function(){
    $("#displayer *").removeClass('highlight');
    var1 = $('textarea#description').val().split(' ');
    for (var i=0;i<var1.length;i++){
    $("#displayer *").highlight(var1[i], "highlight")};
    }),1000);
    });
    });
 </script>
```

the external php that builds the searched table based on an ajax call is this:

```
echo '<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="5" CELLPADDING="5" id="displayer"><FONT     FACE="ARIAL">';

   echo ' <tr> '; 
echo '   <td width="20" ALIGN="LEFT" height="1">ID</td>'; 
echo '   <td width="89" ALIGN="LEFT" height="1">Date</td> '; 
echo '   <td width="200" ALIGN="LEFT" height="1" >Description</td>'; 
echo '   <td width="89" ALIGN="LEFT" height="1" >Solution</td>'; 
echo '   <td width="20" ALIGN="LEFT" height="1" >User:</td>'; 
echo '   <td ALIGN="LEFT" height="1" >Key?:</td>';
echo '   <td ALIGN="LEFT" height="1" >Part:</td>';
echo '   <td ALIGN="LEFT" height="1" >Classified As:</td>';
echo ' </tr>   '; 
 for ($i=1; $i <= $num_results; $i++)
    {
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result1); 

     echo '<TR BGCOLOR="#EFEFEF">';
     echo '<TD width="20">';
     echo  stripslashes($row['0']) ;
     echo '</TD>';
     echo '<TD width="89" >';
     echo  $row['1'] ;
     echo '</TD>';
     echo '<TD width="200">';
     echo  stripslashes($row['6']) ;
     echo '</TD>';
     echo '<TD width="89">';
     echo  stripslashes($row['11']) ;
     echo '</TD>';
     echo '<TD  width="20">';
     echo  $row['5'] ;
     echo '</TD>';
      echo '<TD>';
      if ($row['8'] == 1)
     {echo  'Yes' ;}
     else 
     {echo 'No' ;}

     echo '</TD>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['10'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['9'].'</td>';

     echo '</TR>';

    }
         echo '</TABLE>';
```

external highlight plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.highlight = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3 && regex.test(this.nodeValue);
        }).replaceWith(function() {
            return (this.nodeValue || "").replace(regex, function(match) {
                return "<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + match + "</span>";
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I think I should add a test for empty with some kind of escape, to solve the first condition, but with the second, I'm not sure what's happening.  Any suggestions are definitely appreciated.  Sorry for the post being huge and convoluted, but I wanted everyone to have all the information I could provide.

Comment: Could you post something on jsFiddle to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I'll try to come up with some test values to use, but yeah, I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: try running it, if the array gets long enough, it breaks.  You can't see the table lose it's formatting in this one, because the table doesn't have much formatting, but it will still fail to work after the first time if it's long enough.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this, at least on Chrome, with about 10 rows of data.

Comment: even after you start deleting?  It's breaking for me the first time.  Chrome as well.

Comment: @Brian Hoover So it looks like this adds a whole mess of span tags, including some between the <tbody> that chrome inserts and the first <tr> which I believe is causing all of my issues.  I will have to look more deeply into what I can do to remedy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#description").keydown(function(){
        delay((function(){
        var divClone = $("#disp_hidden .serial_display").clone();
        $("#displayer .serial_display").replaceWith(divClone);
                if ($.trim($('textarea#description').val()) != ''){
                var1 = $('textarea#description').val().trim().split(' ');
            for (var i=0;i<var1.length;i++){
            $("#displayer *").highlight(var1[i], "highlight")};
            };
        }),1000);
        });
        });
```

hidden table clone, replaces at new edit, fixed.