# Assign and retrieve an html table to a javascript variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to backup an html table to afterwards filter it using jquery:

```
$('.row').closest('td').not(':contains(' + v + ')').parent('tr').remove();
```

Since I do **remove()** I have to back up the rows before:

```
var allTable = $('#mytable').html();
```

And then, when filter is performed I turn back to previous table data:

```
$('#mytable').html($(allTable));
```

But this does not work. If I do:

```
alert($(allTable).filter('tr').length);
```

next to the first assignment, zero rows are returned.

Please, can you assist me?

Comment: Don't remove, just hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter()` is used to find elements within an array of elements. This isn't what you need. You're looking to `find()` the child elements within another. Also, storing the HTML only to turn it back in to a jQuery object is a little redundant - you may as well just store the jQuery object itself. Try this:

```
var $table = $('#mytable');
$table.remove(); // use your existing logic here
alert($table.find('tr').length);
$table.appendTo('body'); // add the table back in to the DOM when conditions are met
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C9pSf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when using a highlight function.  I solved it by cloning the table into a hidden div and restoring it from there, instead of from a variable.  see [jquery highlight() breaking in dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941004/jquery-highlight-breaking-in-dynamic-table)

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this problem?

I suggest a workaround.

Instead of using your cloned table, make a (temporary) copy of it and use it for alert.

```
var alertTable = allTable;
alert($(alertTable).filter('tr').length);
```